# Сортировка происходит только при повторном открытии файла

Tags: java, javafx

Сортировка по алфавиту происходит только после того, как я открою файл второй раз. В итоге получаю отсортированные данные по два раза. Как сделать так, чтобы все сортировалось с первого раза?

И еще одно: как сделать нумерованный список в первом столбце?

```
ObservableList<Car> arrNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void ButtonOneAction(ActionEvent event){
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("TXT Files", "*.txt"));
    if (selectedFile != null){
        listfiles.getItems().add(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        System.out.println("file invalid");
    }

    try(BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()))){
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = bReader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] fileReader = sCurrentLine.split("\\s");
            arrNames.add(new Car(fileReader[0],Integer.parseInt(fileReader[1]),Integer.parseInt(fileReader[2])));

        }
    } catch (IOException e){       
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Comparator<Car> nameComp = new CarNameComparator();
    FXCollections.sort(tableView.getItems(),nameComp);

    tableModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, String>("Name"));
    tableSpeed.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, String>("Speed"));
    tablePrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, String>("Price"));

    tableView.setItems(arrNames);
}
```

[image: Результатблаблабла]

Comment: `FXCollections.sort(/*tableView.getItems()*/ arrNames,nameComp);`, про нумерованный список не понял

Comment: Сдесь очень неудобно что либо прикрепить. Если у вас есть время, могу ли я скинуть вам в личку скрин, файл и код? Но если кратко, то в моей программе есть 4 столбца. В 2, 3 и 4 данные. А в 1 хочу чтобы просто выводились цифры от 1 до количества записей

Comment: 5 минут, как раз пишу ответ

Comment: Да блин, как тут красивый комментарий добавить(
я сейчас могу все с скринами красиво описать, но нет... Придется отвечать на собственный вопрос

Comment: В комментариях нельзя картинки, только примитивное форматирование а-ля курсив, bold, моношир :)

Comment: а вы есть где-нибудь в соцсетсях либо других форумах? если конечно у вас есть немного времени...)

Comment: будем считать что нет меня нигде, кроме stackoverflow. Тут можно создать чат-рум, но я не умею )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При первом открытии вы сортируете пустую (на момент сортировки) таблицу. Для нумерации можно создать ещё одно поле в классе `Car`:

```
public class Car {
    // не или StringProperty если удобнее\привычнее
    private IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(null, "id", -1);

    public setId( int id ) {
        this.id.set( id );
    }
    ...
}


public void ButtonOneAction(ActionEvent event){
    ...
    Comparator<Car> nameComp = new CarNameComparator();
    // здесь была сортировка пустого листа
    //FXCollections.sort(tableView.getItems(),nameComp);
    FXCollections.sort(arrNames,nameComp);

    for ( int i = 0; i < arrNames.size(); i++ ) {
        arrName.get(i).setId( i+1 );
    }
    // не уверен, что это валидно для Integer, не на чем проверить, но принцип такой
    someIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, Integer>("id"));
    // возможно нужно будет написать обработчик для отрисовки ячейки id

    tableModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, String>("Name"));
    tableSpeed.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, String>("Speed"));
    tablePrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car, String>("Price"));

    tableView.setItems(arrNames);
}
```